# PostGIS tesselation invalidating polyhedralsurfaces

Tags: postgis, self-intersection, tesselation, geometries, polyhedralsurface

We are trying to visualise prefabricated concrete elements.
These elements are exported in an ifc format. https://technical.buildingsmart.org/standards/ifc/ifc-formats/

We have already been able to individualise the different concrete elements and the corresponding coordinates in these ifc files.

Using PostGIS we are able to create negative volumes for these elements. we need the left over space which lasts when making a 3Dbox around the concrete element.
[image: Concrete element picture]

The Coordinates for the element are made up of Cartesian points. Using a couple of scripts we are able to create a polyhedral surface for the element.

> ‘POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((120000 24005 8605,119860 24005 8605,119860
> 24200 8605,120000 24200 8605,120000 24005 8605)),((119911 29995
> 8000,119915 29995 8020,119915 24200 8020,119911 24200 8000,119911
> 29995 8000)),((119915 29995 8020,119945 29995 8020,119945 24200
> 8020,119915 24200 8020,119915 29995 8020)),((119945 29995 8020,119950
> 29995 8000,119950 24200 8000,119945 24200 8020,119945 29995
> 8020)),((119950 29995 8000,120000 29995 8000,120000 24200 8000,119950
> 24200 8000,119950 29995 8000)),((120000 24200 8605,119860 24200
> 8605,119860 24200 8000,119911 24200 8000,119915 24200 8020,119945
> 24200 8020,119950 24200 8000,120000 24200 8000,120000 24200
> 8605)),((119860 29995 8000,119911 29995 8000,119911 24200 8000,119860
> 24200 8000,119860 29995 8000)),((120000 29995 8000,119950 29995
> 8000,119945 29995 8020,119915 29995 8020,119911 29995 8000,119860
> 29995 8000,119860 29995 8500,120000 29995 8500,120000 29995
> 8000)),((120000 29995 8500,119860 29995 8500,119860 29800 8500,120000
> 29800 8500,120000 29995 8500)),((120000 29800 8500,119860 29800
> 8500,119860 29800 8960,120000 29800 8960,120000 29800 8500)),((120000
> 29995 8960,120000 29800 8960,119860 29800 8960,119860 29995
> 8960,120000 29995 8960)),((120000 24005 8605,120000 24200 8605,120000
> 24200 8000,120000 29995 8000,120000 29995 8500,120000 29800
> 8500,120000 29800 8960,120000 29995 8960,120000 29995 10840,120000
> 24005 10481,120000 24005 8605)),((119860 24005 8605,120000 24005
> 8605,120000 24005 10481,119860 24005 10481,119860 24005
> 8605)),((119860 29995 8960,119860 29800 8960,119860 29800 8500,119860
> 29995 8500,119860 29995 8000,119860 24200 8000,119860 24200
> 8605,119860 24005 8605,119860 24005 10481,119860 29995 10840,119860
> 29995 8960)),((120000 29995 8960,119860 29995 8960,119860 29995
> 10840,120000 29995 10840,120000 29995 8960)),((119860 24005
> 10481,120000 24005 10481,120000 29995 10840,119860 29995 10840,119860
> 24005 10481)))’

The validity of the element is checked with (select ST_Volume(ST_MakeSolid(
This polyhedralsurface has a volume of 2198022249.9999743.

A script gives the polyhedralsurface of the extent of the element. Using Box3d gave me problems so i created a function __gvb_3dextentphs to give the polyhedralsurface of the extent.

> 'POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((119860 24005 8000,119860 24005 10840,119860
> 29995 10840,119860 29995 8000,119860 24005 8000)),((119860 24005
> 8000,120000 24005 8000,120000 24005 10840,119860 24005 10840,119860
> 24005 8000)),((119860 24005 8000,119860 29995 8000,120000 29995
> 8000,120000 24005 8000,119860 24005 8000)),((120000 24005 8000,120000
> 29995 8000,120000 29995 10840,120000 24005 10840,120000 24005
> 8000)),((119860 29995 8000,119860 29995 10840,120000 29995
> 10840,120000 29995 8000,119860 29995 8000)),((119860 24005
> 10840,120000 24005 10840,120000 29995 10840,119860 29995 10840,119860
> 24005 10840)))'

We then use a script to create a negative of the element using the ST_3DDifference of the extent vs the element itself

```
inner join lateral (select
    case when directiontype = 'element' then ST_AsText(ST_3DDifference( __gvb_3dextentphs(phs) , phs)) end as negbekisting  
    ,case when directiontype = 'element' then ST_AsText(ST_3DDifference( phs , __gvb_3dextentphs(phs) )) end as negelement  
) tbl100 on true

inner join lateral (select
    case when directiontype = 'element' then ST_AsText(ST_3DUnion(negbekisting,ST_Reverse(negelement))) end as neg  
) tbl200 on true;
```

The result is a geometrycollection with 3 polyhedralsurfaces.

> 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION Z (
>
> POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((119860 29838.333333333336 8960,119860 29995 8960,119860 29995
> 8500,119860 29838.333333333336 8960)),((119860 29800 8500,119860
> 29838.333333333336 8960,119860 29995 8500,119860 29800 8500)),((119860 29800 8960,119860 29838.333333333336 8960,119860 29800 8500,119860
> 29800 8960)),((119860 29995 8500,119869.55967201985 29995
> 8960,119878.23155369554 29995 8500,119860 29995 8500)),((119860 29995
> 8960,119869.55967201985 29995 8960,119860 29995 8500,119860 29995
> 8960)),((119869.55967201985 29995 8960,119874.64757305454 29995
> 8960,119878.23155369554 29995 8500,119869.55967201985 29995
> 8960)),((119877.64547905154 29995 8960,119878.23155369554 29995
> 8500,119874.64757305454 29995 8960,119877.64547905154 29995
> 8960)),((119878.23155369554 29995 8500,119877.64547905154 29995
> 8960,119879.80257614062 29995 8960,119878.23155369554 29995
> 8500)),((119878.23155369554 29995 8500,119879.80257614062 29995
> 8960,119884.64788732395 29995 8500,119878.23155369554 29995
> 8500)),((119879.80257614062 29995 8960,119907.32394366196 29995
> 8960,119884.64788732395 29995 8500,119879.80257614062 29995
> 8960)),((119884.64788732395 29995 8500,119907.32394366196 29995
> 8960,119954.68309859154 29995 8500,119884.64788732395 29995
> 8500)),((119907.32394366196 29995 8960,119963.59154929579 29995
> 8960,119954.68309859154 29995 8500,119907.32394366196 29995
> 8960)),((119954.68309859154 29995 8500,119963.59154929579 29995
> 8960,120000 29995 8500,119954.68309859154 29995
> 8500)),((119963.59154929579 29995 8960,120000 29995 8960,120000 29995
> 8500,119963.59154929579 29995 8960)),((120000 29800 8500,120000
> 29838.333333333336 8960,120000 29800 8960,120000 29800 8500)),((120000 29838.333333333336 8960,120000 29995 8500,120000 29995 8960,120000 29838.333333333336 8960)),((120000 29838.333333333336 8960,120000 29800 8500,120000 29995 8500,120000 29838.333333333336 8960)),((120000
> 29800 8500,119860 29800 8500,119860 29995 8500,120000 29800
> 8500)),((120000 29800 8500,119860 29995 8500,119878.23155369554 29995
> 8500,120000 29800 8500)),((119954.68309859154 29995 8500,120000 29800
> 8500,119884.64788732395 29995 8500,119954.68309859154 29995
> 8500)),((119884.64788732395 29995 8500,120000 29800
> 8500,119878.23155369554 29995 8500,119884.64788732395 29995
> 8500)),((120000 29995 8500,120000 29800 8500,119954.68309859154 29995
> 8500,120000 29995 8500)),((120000 29800 8960,119860 29800 8960,119860
> 29800 8500,120000 29800 8960)),((120000 29800 8960,119860 29800
> 8500,120000 29800 8500,120000 29800 8960)),((120000 29838.333333333336
> 8960,119860 29800 8960,120000 29800 8960,120000 29838.333333333336
> 8960)),((120000 29995 8960,119860 29800 8960,120000 29838.333333333336
> 8960,120000 29995 8960)),((119963.59154929579 29995 8960,119860 29800
> 8960,120000 29995 8960,119963.59154929579 29995
> 8960)),((119963.59154929579 29995 8960,119907.32394366196 29995
> 8960,119860 29800 8960,119963.59154929579 29995
> 8960)),((119907.32394366196 29995 8960,119879.80257614062 29995
> 8960,119860 29800 8960,119907.32394366196 29995
> 8960)),((119879.80257614062 29995 8960,119877.64547905154 29995
> 8960,119860 29800 8960,119879.80257614062 29995
> 8960)),((119877.64547905154 29995 8960,119874.64757305454 29995
> 8960,119860 29800 8960,119877.64547905154 29995
> 8960)),((119874.64757305454 29995 8960,119869.55967201985 29995
> 8960,119860 29800 8960,119874.64757305454 29995
> 8960)),((119869.55967201985 29995 8960,119860 29838.333333333336
> 8960,119860 29800 8960,119869.55967201985 29995 8960)),((119860 29995
> 8960,119860 29838.333333333336 8960,119869.55967201985 29995
> 8960,119860 29995 8960)))
>
> ,POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((119860 24200 8605,119860 24200 8092.45409015025,119860 24005
> 8000,119860 24200 8605)),((119860 24005 8605,119860 24200 8605,119860
> 24005 8000,119860 24005 8605)),((119860 24005 8000,120000 24005
> 8000,119970.17605633804 24005 8605,119860 24005 8000)),((119860 24005
> 8605,119860 24005 8000,119970.17605633804 24005 8605,119860 24005
> 8605)),((120000 24005 8000,120000 24005 8605,119970.17605633804 24005
> 8605,120000 24005 8000)),((120000 24200 8000,120000 24200 8605,120000
> 24158.45950704225 8605,120000 24200 8000)),((120000 24005 8000,120000 24200 8000,120000 24158.45950704225 8605,120000 24005 8000)),((120000
> 24005 8605,120000 24005 8000,120000 24158.45950704225 8605,120000
> 24005 8605)),((120000 24200 8000,120000 24005 8000,119997.05096729845
> 24200 8000,120000 24200 8000)),((119997.05096729845 24200 8000,120000
> 24005 8000,119992.95644255576 24200 8000,119997.05096729845 24200
> 8000)),((119992.95644255576 24200 8000,120000 24005
> 8000,119992.38390634433 24200 8000,119992.95644255576 24200
> 8000)),((119992.38390634433 24200 8000,120000 24005
> 8000,119992.04654816852 24200 8000,119992.38390634433 24200
> 8000)),((119992.04654816852 24200 8000,120000 24005 8000,119950 24200
> 8000,119992.04654816852 24200 8000)),((119950 24200 8000,120000 24005
> 8000,119945 24200 8000,119950 24200 8000)),((119945 24200 8000,120000
> 24005 8000,119915 24200 8000,119945 24200 8000)),((119915 24200
> 8000,120000 24005 8000,119911 24200 8000,119915 24200 8000)),((119860
> 24200 8000,119864.55759599333 24200 8000,119860 24005 8000,119860
> 24200 8000)),((119864.55759599333 24200 8000,119911 24200 8000,119860
> 24005 8000,119864.55759599333 24200 8000)),((119911 24200 8000,120000
> 24005 8000,119860 24005 8000,119911 24200 8000)),((119860 24200
> 8092.45409015025,119860 24200 8000,119860 24005 8000,119860 24200 8092.45409015025)),((119945 24200 8000,119860 24200 8605,120000 24200 8605,119945 24200 8000)),((119864.55759599333 24200 8000,119860 24200
> 8000,119860 24200 8092.45409015025,119864.55759599333 24200
> 8000)),((119860 24200 8605,119864.55759599333 24200 8000,119860 24200
> 8092.45409015025,119860 24200 8605)),((119860 24200 8605,119911 24200 8000,119864.55759599333 24200 8000,119860 24200 8605)),((119915 24200
> 8000,119860 24200 8605,119945 24200 8000,119915 24200 8000)),((119911
> 24200 8000,119860 24200 8605,119915 24200 8000,119911 24200
> 8000)),((119950 24200 8000,119945 24200 8000,120000 24200 8605,119950
> 24200 8000)),((119997.05096729845 24200 8000,119992.95644255576 24200
> 8000,120000 24200 8605,119997.05096729845 24200 8000)),((120000 24200
> 8000,119997.05096729845 24200 8000,120000 24200 8605,120000 24200
> 8000)),((119992.95644255576 24200 8000,119992.38390634433 24200
> 8000,120000 24200 8605,119992.95644255576 24200
> 8000)),((119992.38390634433 24200 8000,119992.04654816852 24200
> 8000,120000 24200 8605,119992.38390634433 24200
> 8000)),((119992.04654816852 24200 8000,119950 24200 8000,120000 24200
> 8605,119992.04654816852 24200 8000)),((120000 24200 8605,119860 24005
> 8605,119970.17605633804 24005 8605,120000 24200 8605)),((120000
> 24158.45950704225 8605,120000 24200 8605,119970.17605633804 24005 8605,120000 24158.45950704225 8605)),((120000 24005 8605,120000
> 24158.45950704225 8605,119970.17605633804 24005 8605,120000 24005 8605)),((120000 24200 8605,119860 24200 8605,119860 24005 8605,120000
> 24200 8605)))
>
> ,POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((119860 24841.85831142751 10531.155614992065,119860 29995
> 10840,119860 24841.85831142751 10531.155614992065,119860
> 24841.85831142751 10531.155614992065)),((119860 24005 10840,119860 29995 10840,119860 24841.85831142751 10531.155614992065,119860 24005
> 10840)),((119860 24841.85831142751 10531.155614992065,119860
> 24841.85831142751 10531.155614992065,119860 24236.00419185799 10494.84482552204,119860 24841.85831142751 10531.155614992065)),((119860 24236.00419185799 10494.84482552204,119860 24841.85831142751 10531.155614992065,119860 24236.00419185799 10494.84482552204,119860 24236.00419185799 10494.84482552204)),((119860 24005 10840,119860 24841.85831142751 10531.155614992065,119860 24236.00419185799 10494.84482552204,119860 24005 10840)),((119860 24236.00419185799 10494.84482552204,119860
> 24236.00419185799 10494.84482552204,119860 24224.00056587744 10494.125409540902,119860 24236.00419185799 10494.84482552204)),((119860 24005 10840,119860 24236.00419185799 10494.84482552204,119860 24224.00056587744 10494.125409540902,119860 24005 10840)),((119860 24195.393793680814 10492.410913511088,119860
> 24005 10840,119860 24224.00056587744 10494.125409540902,119860
> 24195.393793680814 10492.410913511088)),((119860 24005 10840,119860 24195.393793680814 10492.410913511088,119860 24038.466961379054 10483.005782827226,119860 24005 10840)),((119860 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874,119860 24005 10840,119860 24038.466961379054 10483.005782827226,119860 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874)),((119860 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874,119860 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874,119860 24038.466961379054 10483.005782827226,119860 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874)),((119860 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874,119860 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874,119860 24005 10481,119860 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874)),((119860
> 24005 10840,119860 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874,119860 24005
> 10481,119860 24005 10840)),((119860 24005 10840,119970.17605633804
> 24005 10481,120000 24005 10840,119860 24005 10840)),((119860 24005
> 10840,119877.69718309859 24005 10481,119970.17605633804 24005
> 10481,119860 24005 10840)),((119860 24005 10481,119877.69718309859
> 24005 10481,119860 24005 10840,119860 24005 10481)),((119860 29995
> 10840,120000 24005 10840,120000 29995 10840,119860 29995
> 10840)),((119860 29995 10840,119860 24005 10840,120000 24005
> 10840,119860 29995 10840)),((120000 24005 10481,120000 24005
> 10840,119970.17605633804 24005 10481,120000 24005 10481)),((120000
> 24035.80123982925 10482.846017545693,120000 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874,120000 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874,120000 24035.80123982925 10482.846017545693)),((120000 24005 10840,120000 24035.80123982925 10482.846017545693,120000 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874,120000 24005 10840)),((120000 24005 10840,120000 24029.54862701719 10482.471278313718,120000 24035.80123982925 10482.846017545693,120000 24005 10840)),((120000 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874,120000 24677.21319162238 10521.287902469521,120000 24677.21319162238 10521.287902469521,120000 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874)),((120000 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874,120000 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874,120000 24677.21319162238 10521.287902469521,120000 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874)),((120000 24005 10840,120000 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874,120000 24677.21319162238 10521.287902469521,120000 24005 10840)),((120000 24005 10481,120000 24029.54862701719
> 10482.471278313718,120000 24005 10840,120000 24005 10481)),((120000 24677.21319162238 10521.287902469521,120000 29995 10840,120000 24005 10840,120000 24677.21319162238 10521.287902469521)),((120000
> 24677.21319162238 10521.287902469521,120000 29995 10840,120000 24677.21319162238 10521.287902469521,120000 24677.21319162238 10521.287902469521)),((119860 29995 10840,120000 29995 10840,120000 24677.21319162238 10521.287902469521,119860 29995 10840)),((120000 24035.80123982925 10482.846017545693,119860 29995 10840,120000 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874,120000 24035.80123982925 10482.846017545693)),((120000 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874,119860 29995 10840,120000 24677.21319162238 10521.287902469521,120000 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874)),((120000 24005 10481,119860 29995 10840,120000 24035.80123982925 10482.846017545693,120000 24005 10481)),((119860 29995 10840,120000 24005 10481,119970.17605633804 24005 10481,119860
> 29995 10840)),((119860 24841.85831142751 10531.155614992065,119860
> 29995 10840,119877.69718309859 24005 10481,119860 24841.85831142751
> 10531.155614992065)),((119877.69718309859 24005 10481,119860 29995 10840,119970.17605633804 24005 10481,119877.69718309859 24005
> 10481)),((119860 24005 10481,119860 24036.159213845203
> 10482.867472081874,119877.69718309859 24005 10481,119860 24005 10481)),((119860 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874,119860
> 24038.466961379054 10483.005782827226,119877.69718309859 24005 10481,119860 24036.159213845203 10482.867472081874)),((119860
> 24038.466961379054 10483.005782827226,119860 24224.00056587744 10494.125409540902,119877.69718309859 24005 10481,119860 24038.466961379054 10483.005782827226)),((119860 24224.00056587744 10494.125409540902,119860 24236.00419185799 10494.84482552204,119877.69718309859 24005 10481,119860 24224.00056587744 10494.125409540902)),((119860 24236.00419185799 10494.84482552204,119860 24841.85831142751 10531.155614992065,119877.69718309859 24005 10481,119860 24236.00419185799 10494.84482552204))) )'

All appears correct, we can even visualize the negative of the concrete shape with ST_AsX3D in https://postgis.net/docs/support/viewers/x3d_viewer.htm .

[image]

the first 2 polyhedralsurfaces are correct. The 3rd polyhedralsurface is the slanted volume which has been tessellated into 40 triangles. It gives a “TriangulatedSurface is invalid : inconsistent orientation of PolyhedralSurface detected” error upon validating ST_Volume(ST_MakeSolid(.

In this specific case the volume is slanted, in other cases we have had problems with the a simple rectangular volume, so the shape does nog appear to have much of an impact.

I have already tried using a custom function based on ST_SnapToGrid to make get rid of the extremely small polygons (which are actually linestrings) in the polyhedralsurfaces made by non-rounded coordinates, to no avail. I just receive different errors. “Solid is invalid : PolyhedralSurface (shell) 0 is invalid: self intersects”.

In this specific case, the polyhedralsurface containing 40 polygons turns into a polyhedralsurface with 28 polygons. Followed by a “Solid is invalid : PolyhedralSurface (shell) 0 is invalid: self intersects” error.

```
DECLARE

geomtype text; geomnewtype text;
geomnew text;
pathnr int;
pathnum int;
pathcountmax int;

begin 

    geomtype = upper(GeometryType(geom1));

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Tijdelijke tabel met de geometrieën
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS gvbsnaptogrid_dump;
    CREATE Temporary TABLE gvbsnaptogrid_dump as 
    SELECT
    dump1.path as pathnew
    ,cast( null as integer[]) as pathpart
    ,pathcount
    ,tbl100.geom
    ,tbl200.points
    ,ST_AsText(dump1.geom) as geomoriginal
    from ST_Dump(geom1) as dump1
    
        inner join lateral (select
            dump1.path as path
            ,ST_AsText(ST_SnapToGrid(dump1.geom,'point(0 0 0)',size,size,size,size)) as geom    
        )tbl100 on true 
    
        inner join lateral (select                                                          --ST_NPoints werkt niet omdat een tin altijd verondersteld is 4 punten te hebben, dus volgt een foutmelding
            ARRAY_LENGTH(tbl100.path,1) as pathcount
            ,length(tbl100.geom) - length(replace(tbl100.geom,',','')) + 1 as points
        )tbl200 on true 

        where points > 3;   

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Pathnew aanpassen -> vervolgnullen bijplaatsen zodat de pathnew overal dezelfde lengte heeft
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    pathcountmax = (select max(pathcount) from gvbsnaptogrid_dump);

    for pathnr in 1..pathcountmax Loop
        update gvbsnaptogrid_dump set pathnew       =   ARRAY_APPEND(pathnew,0) where pathcount < pathnr;       
    end loop;

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Kopie maken van de originele tabel, voor controle doeleinden
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS gvbsnaptogrid_dump1;
    CREATE Temporary TABLE gvbsnaptogrid_dump1 as
    select * from gvbsnaptogrid_dump;
    
    create index gvbsnaptogrid_dump1_idx1 on gvbsnaptogrid_dump1(pathnew);  -- index en cluster zorgt er voor dat de tabel zeker deze volgorde aanneemt 
    cluster gvbsnaptogrid_dump1 using gvbsnaptogrid_dump1_idx1;

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Collectie doen van de gedumpte geometrieën
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    for pathnum in REVERSE pathcountmax..2 Loop
--  pathnum = 4;

        -- alle paden van een hoger niveau gewoon overnemen
        update gvbsnaptogrid_dump1 set pathpart         =   pathnew
                                                            where   pathcount < pathnum ;

        -- de paden van deze niveau's en lagere niveau's wijzigen naar niveau gevolgd door 0'en
        update gvbsnaptogrid_dump1 set pathpart         =   ARRAY_APPEND(pathnew[1:pathnum-1],0)
                                                            where   pathcount >= pathnum ;

        -- de collection doen in een tabel
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS gvbsnaptogrid_dump2;
        CREATE Temporary TABLE gvbsnaptogrid_dump2 as 
        select
        pathpart as pathnew
        ,pathpart
        ,pathcount
        ,ST_AsText(geomcollect) as geom
        from (select pathpart,pathcount,ST_Collect(geom) as geomcollect
              from gvbsnaptogrid_dump1 group by pathpart,pathcount) as dd;

        -- de collection tabel in de oorspronkelijke tabel opnemen
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS gvbsnaptogrid_dump1;
        CREATE Temporary TABLE gvbsnaptogrid_dump1 as
        select * from gvbsnaptogrid_dump2;

    end loop;
    
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Collectie doen van de gedumpte geometrieën
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    geomnew = (select ST_AsText(ST_Collect(geom)) from gvbsnaptogrid_dump1);

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Geometrie types wijzigen
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    geomnewtype = upper(GeometryType(geomnew));
    
    if geomtype = 'POLYHEDRALSURFACE' and geomnewtype = 'MULTIPOLYGON' then
        geomnew = replace(geomnew,'MULTIPOLYGON','POLYHEDRALSURFACE');
    end if;

    geomnew = replace(geomnew,'TIN Z','POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z');
    geomnew = replace(geomnew,'MULTIPOLYGON Z','POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z');  
    geomnew = replace(geomnew,'POLYGON Z','POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z');

RETURN geomnew;
```

> 'POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((119860 24005 10840,119860 29995 10840,119860
> 24842 10531,119860 24005 10840)),((119860 24005 10840,119860 24842
> 10531,119860 24236 10495,119860 24005 10840)),((119860 24005
> 10840,119860 24236 10495,119860 24224 10494,119860 24005
> 10840)),((119860 24195 10492,119860 24005 10840,119860 24224
> 10494,119860 24195 10492)),((119860 24005 10840,119860 24195
> 10492,119860 24038 10483,119860 24005 10840)),((119860 24036
> 10483,119860 24005 10840,119860 24038 10483,119860 24036
> 10483)),((119860 24005 10840,119860 24036 10483,119860 24005
> 10481,119860 24005 10840)),((119860 24005 10840,119970 24005
> 10481,120000 24005 10840,119860 24005 10840)),((119860 24005
> 10840,119878 24005 10481,119970 24005 10481,119860 24005
> 10840)),((119860 24005 10481,119878 24005 10481,119860 24005
> 10840,119860 24005 10481)),((119860 29995 10840,120000 24005
> 10840,120000 29995 10840,119860 29995 10840)),((119860 29995
> 10840,119860 24005 10840,120000 24005 10840,119860 29995
> 10840)),((120000 24005 10481,120000 24005 10840,119970 24005
> 10481,120000 24005 10481)),((120000 24005 10840,120000 24030
> 10482,120000 24036 10483,120000 24005 10840)),((120000 24005
> 10840,120000 24036 10483,120000 24677 10521,120000 24005
> 10840)),((120000 24005 10481,120000 24030 10482,120000 24005
> 10840,120000 24005 10481)),((120000 24677 10521,120000 29995
> 10840,120000 24005 10840,120000 24677 10521)),((119860 29995
> 10840,120000 29995 10840,120000 24677 10521,119860 29995
> 10840)),((120000 24036 10483,119860 29995 10840,120000 24677
> 10521,120000 24036 10483)),((120000 24005 10481,119860 29995
> 10840,120000 24036 10483,120000 24005 10481)),((119860 29995
> 10840,120000 24005 10481,119970 24005 10481,119860 29995
> 10840)),((119860 24842 10531,119860 29995 10840,119878 24005
> 10481,119860 24842 10531)),((119878 24005 10481,119860 29995
> 10840,119970 24005 10481,119878 24005 10481)),((119860 24005
> 10481,119860 24036 10483,119878 24005 10481,119860 24005
> 10481)),((119860 24036 10483,119860 24038 10483,119878 24005
> 10481,119860 24036 10483)),((119860 24038 10483,119860 24224
> 10494,119878 24005 10481,119860 24038 10483)),((119860 24224
> 10494,119860 24236 10495,119878 24005 10481,119860 24224
> 10494)),((119860 24236 10495,119860 24842 10531,119878 24005
> 10481,119860 24236 10495)))'

The visualization work perfectly.

[image: Slanted volume]

Using ST_MakeValid on the individual polygons in the polyhedralsurface does not have an impact because the individual polygons are valid.

This is just 1 very simple 3d concrete element and it gives errors. It feels like I am playing the lottery using PostGIS on all other elements, we get PostGIS errors about 60% of the time. These errors include…

- TriangulatedSurface is invalid : inconsistent orientation of PolyhedralSurface detected at edge 1
- Solid is invalid : PolyhedralSurface (shell) 0 is invalid: self intersects
- Solid is invalid : PolyhedralSurface (shell) 0 is not closed

Is there a reason why the tessellation in ST_3DUnion, ST_3DDifference, ST_3DIntersection causes such small triangles? It makes it extremely hard to troubleshoot.

It feels like we are forgetting a crucial step in performing calculations in PostGIS, this should be easy.